# microsoft CRM data model, table (field names, entity/attributes etc..)

Tags: database-connection, dynamics-crm

Where can I find online reference for diagrams or text/XML dump of Microsoft CRM (2013 or 2015) table/fields, entity/attributes .  I don't have access to an instance of the software, but need a heads up on structure and naming conventions.

Comment: then start a free trial http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=252780

Comment: done. thanks.  good resource.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bunch of diagrams for 2013 can be found [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-GB/download/details.aspx?id=41669)